# Pop up window in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i bring up my messages in a pop up window with asp.net-C#?
im cool with javascript !
Is there any idea related with c#?

Comment: Take a look at AjaxControlToolkit's [PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx) A great explaination of how to implement it can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ASPModalInAction.aspx).

Comment: keep in mind, those ACT controls (mentioned below) are just server-side wrappers for javascript. a "popup" in the context of websites is just another window. jquery FTW.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of Ajax-> popUpControl

```
<ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="DateTextBox"
    PopupControlID="Panel1"
    Position="Bottom" />
```

the contents inside the "panel1"(Panel) will popup.
for more info
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx