# I need pop up a window on button click

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pop up window in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625669/pop-up-window-in-asp-net)

I need to pop up a window on a button click so that the popped up window contains a checkboxlist and also I need to get the values which were checked in the checkboxlist which is present in the popped up window.

Is there any way to do this if so please help me?
else
suggest any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ModalPopup of AjaxToolKit control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server"
TargetControlID="LinkButton1"
PopupControlID="Panel1"
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
DropShadow="true" 
OkControlID="OkButton" 
OnOkScript="onOk()"
CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel3" >
    <Animations>
        <OnShowing> ..  </OnShowing>
        <OnShown>   ..  </OnShown>    
        <OnHiding>  ..  </OnHiding>            
        <OnHidden>  ..  </OnHidden>            
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

If you are new about this then visit this link:[ModalPopup Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so first what I am about to explain is Javascript (that's what you need), then with the Javascript variables what you do with the data collected in the Javascript is your ASP.net business.

You are looking for an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) request, if you don't have any idea, I recommend you to take one of the w3schools introduction tutorials.

So in your javascript you must save the variables, send it to the current page (with AJAX) and the collect the data fron the URL in ASP.net